# How to create an xml file and write in android and put into raw folder

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to create an xml file, and write in android, and where to put the file  to be accessed again? Is it possible to put it into a raw folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can anybody tell how to create a xml file and write in android

Use [Java I/O](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/pkg.html).

> where to put the file for aceess again

Use [`getFilesDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) for a place in the on-board flash that is available to your application.

> is it possible to put into raw folder ?

No, sorry, that cannot be modified at runtime.